# Endpoints datastore - query with and without ancestors

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

Similar to the [keys_with_ancestors.html](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/keys_with_ancestors.html) example I need to query a model by it's parent.
But in addition on a different API request I need to query the same model without the parent restriction.

The use case is that I have Tasks associated with Users, I need one API call listing the tasks of a given user and one listing all tasks.
User need to be parent of Task to allow transactions.

If I follow the keys_with_ancestors example I can't manage to to create the 'list all tasks' api - since the query building is done on the Task object and looks for the parent from the request.

I can give up the parent and have a user_email property in the task and just have it as an optional query parameter - but this seems a bad solution.

Any better idea?

Comment: I've managed to find a solution (which I don't full understand): it seems that having the query_method on completely different path works. At first I had one on path='users/{parent}/jobs' and the second on path='users/jobs' but if I the second on path='jobs' it works.